# Heading is overlapping on my website, it is overlapping itself?

Tags: html, css

The heading is overlapping over itself, I don't know how to fix this. Here's a screenshot I've included -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/16mkj7Uapba3MRWGD7vabiCvcfNxO0jeG/view?usp=sharing

I tried `<br>` tags but nothing worked.

`<p class="has-large-font-size"><strong>Top Best Offline Music Players for Android in 2019</strong></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `line-height: normal`

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your line height to stop the overlapping in the page